# More succinct way of checking deep property values

Tags: javascript, lodash

Often when checking if a specific property has a value, you have to traverse some object properties or arrays.  This leads to long statements like below, just to avoid an `error can't read property ____ of undefined`.

Is there a way to write this more succinctly? Possibly ES6 has something? I thought I remember some libraries like Lodash providing helper methods but can't find them.

```
if (
  user &&
  user.profile.pets &&
  user.profile.pets[0] &&
  user.profile.pets[0].type === "dog"
) {
```

Comment: [get](https://lodash.com/docs#get)?

Comment: The lodash method you're looking for might be [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get), but otherwise es6 provides no other way of making that shorter. There is, however, [a proposal for safe property access](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) using the `?.` syntax, but that has a long way to go before anyone supports it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Lodash when data is undefined or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780028/how-to-use-lodash-when-data-is-undefined-or-null)

Answer (score 2):

Lodash has two methods: `_.has` and `_.get`.

`_.has(object, path)` checks if path is a direct property of object.

`_.get(object, path, defValue)` Gets the value at path of object. If the resolved value is undefined, the `defValue` is returned in its place.

```js
let user = {
  profile: {
pets: [{ type: 'dog' }, { type: 'cat' }]
  }
};

// _.has
console.log(_.has(user, 'profile.pets[0].type')); // true
console.log(_.has(user, 'profile.pets[3].type')); // false

// _.get
console.log(_.get(user, 'profile.pets[0].type')); // dog
console.log(_.get(user, 'profile.pets[3].type')); // undefined
console.log(_.get(user, 'profile.pets[3].type', 'unknown')); // unknown
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```