# How to use Lodash when data is undefined or null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, lodash

In my application If data is undefined or null which is coming from service, my html will not load and I will get "data is undefined" error
so I am tring to use lodash, but dont know how to use it..

In my below ts file

```
    this._PartService.GetDataValues().subscribe(
  result => {
    this.distributionData = this._PartService.part_data.partMasterDataCompleteList[0].partMasterData.plantSupplies.plantSupply
  }
```

I will be getting "partMasterDataCompleteList" as undefiend or null if data is not there, so there I am trying to use Lodash but I dont know how to use it

Comment: What do you mean by trying to use lodash?

Comment: If it can be undefined, you should just handle that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lodash provides quite a few methods to check and get the value you want from an object.

[_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) would actually **return the value** if it exists and would return `undefined` if it does not.

[_.has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#has) would **check if the value exists** and return `true` if it does and `false` if it does not.

[_.hasIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#hasIn) would do the same as `_.has` but would also check if this is an inherited property.

[_.result](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#result) would actually walk the path and return the value as well but with a major difference ... **it would execute any function among the way to get to the value**.

Examples:

```js
var data = { more: { result: 1}}
var data2 = _.create({ 'more': _.create({ 'result': 2 }) });
var data3 = { more: function() { return { result: 1} }}

console.log(_.get(data, 'more.result'))     // 1
console.log(_.has(data, 'more.result'))     // true
console.log(_.hasIn(data2, 'more.result'))  // true
console.log(_.result(data3, 'more.result')) // 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) function.

```
this.distributionData = _.get(this, '_PartService.part_data.partMasterDataCompleteList[0].partMasterData.plantSupplies.plantSupply')
```

Comment: yes - and import it before. In this case with the name _

Comment: I have  "let temp = []; this.weight = temp", here temp is an array, so how can i use ._get for this array

Comment: ow can i use ._get for following code

this.PartServiceData.masterData = result['data'].partMasterDataCompleteList[0];

Answer (score 1):

To handle undefined cases, I use the following :

```
this.distributionData =((((this._PartService.part_data.partMasterDataCompleteList || [])[0] || {}).partMasterData || {}).plantSupplies || {}).plantSupply
```

Although a better approach would be to have the server send an empty array instead of undefined or null.

This is not a lodash issue. It is just about handling the undefined or null case

Comment: Thanks..It worked but for each object I need to keep on adding empty object so I was trying to use Lodash..Please let me know if you know that

Comment: The lodash .get object function might work.

See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get